# Create a post builder skin in a plugin

Tags: plugins, functions, query, hooks, actions

Currently I'm working on a plugin that will display a grid based on post type with many settings to customize it. One of the settings will be to choose between different skins available to display inside the grid.

I would like to offer the possibility to developers to include their own skins with a custom HOOK/Filter.

What is the right way to add this functionality in a plugin?

I was thinking about something like this but I'm not sure if it's the right way and if it will work:

```
// register skin class in plugin
class skinclass {
    //existing skins
    function myclass() {

    }
    do_action('add_custom_skin');
}

// developers register action to include it's own skins (in function.php)
add_action('add_custom_skin','my_custom_skins')
function my_custom_skins($post) {

    function skin1($post) {
        $skin1  = '<article class="skin1-holder">';
        $skin1 .= '<h2 class="skin1-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h2>';
        $skin1 .= '<div class="skin1-excerpt">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>';
        $skin1 .= '</article>';
        return $skin1;
    }

    function skin2($post) {
        $skin2  = '<article class="skin2-holder">';
        $skin2 .= '<h2 class="skin2-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h2>';
        $skin2 .= '<div class="skin2-excerpt">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>';
        $skin2 .= '</article>';
        return $skin2;
    }

}

// get skin function in plugin
$skins = get_class_methods(new skinclass());
// to output skin in a drop down list
foreach ($skins as $skin_name) {
    echo "$skin_name\n";
}

// output skin in front end
$func = 'skin1';
$func();
```

The skin to output will be in a query_posts loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert the `do_action()` inside the class like that, it's gonna give you a fatal error.

Instead you could use an array `$skins` to store all the skin functions (as [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)), and the [magic method `_call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) to call them:

```
class skinclass {

    private $skins = array();

    function __construct() {
        $this->skins = apply_filters( 'add_skin', $this->skins );
    }

    function __call( $name, $post ) {
        if(isset($this->skins[$name]))
            return $this->skins[$name]( $post );
    }

}
```

As you can see I used `apply_filters()` to be able to add skins on initializazion, and then the`__call` is gonna check if the skin exists and, if so, execute it.

So now to add a skin you add a filter that modifies the `$skins` property:

```
// add skin1
add_filter( 'add_skin', function( $skins ){
    $skins['skin1'] = function( $post ) {
        $skin1  = '<article class="skin1-holder">';
        $skin1 .= '<h2 class="skin1-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h2>';
        $skin1 .= '<div class="skin1-excerpt">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>';
        $skin1 .= '</article>';
        return $skin1;
    };
    return $skins;
});

// add skin2
add_filter( 'add_skin', function( $skins ){
    $skins['skin2'] = function( $post ) {
        $skin2  = '<article class="skin2-holder">';
        $skin2 .= '<h2 class="skin2-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h2>';
        $skin2 .= '<div class="skin2-excerpt">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>';
        $skin2 .= '</article>';
        return $skin2;
    };
    return $skins;
});
```

Wait, but what about retrieving the skins list? Well, we can add a method to the class to do that, so inside the class you can add:

```
function get_skins() {
    return array_keys($this->skins);
}
```

---

Ok so now to use the class you need to get an instance:

```
$skinObj = new skinclass();
```

And the rest is very similar to your code:

```
// get skin function in plugin
$skins = $skinObj->get_skins();
// to output skin in a drop down list
foreach ($skins as $skin_name) {
    echo "$skin_name\n";
}

// output skin in front end
$func = 'skin1';
echo $skinObj->$func( $post );
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand, that you add the possibilties for developers to change the html, typical a template part. That is the point, that I think you should use the default functionality for this job. [`get_page_template()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/theme.php#L917) can be overridden via the `page_template` filter.

A simple example for the dev to change your templates from your plugin.

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpse185512_page_template' );
function wpse185512_page_template( $page_template ) {

    if ( is_page( 'my-custom-page-slug' ) ) {
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/custom-page-template.php';
    }

    return $page_template;
}
```

For the include in your plugin use a custom function, that include the file from a path. You find a good reference on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647604/wp-use-file-in-plugin-directory-as-custom-page-template). I think is not helpful to copy this here, much better you see the answers and understand the solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't correspond to my need. My aim is not to modify a template by to add a complete markup from nothing.

Comment: The content of the template define you as developer, like a header.php of a theme have also only a part of a result.

Comment: So, in your answer I can't see how to implement it...

Comment: The last paragraph link to a question, there have fine answers to how to implement in plugins. Do you have read this?

Comment: Yes I have read it. But I still think that it doesn't correspond to my need... I want to add skin to style post in a loop. Not to change a template...